# How to keep a complex object tree on struts2?

Tags: java, events, session, object, struts2

I'm developing a web application with user login support.
When a user logs in I fetch some information from several different places and transform that into objects that will be processed later. These objects will have several different components, including some event handling.
The objects are generic and, using some local information, will have listeners attached.
I don't want to rebuild the entire object tree (including event assignment) on every request. But it doesn't feel right to keep all this stored on the session.

What do you think? What's the best way to maintain this type of information on a Web Application?

Comment: Where *else* would you keep it?! If you want it in-memory, per-user, isn't that where it *belongs*? Unless you can compartmentalize parts of it to avoid recreating things, I don't really see what your (reasonable) options are.

Comment: Without knowing the purpose of these object and given that "they will be used later" it sounds like they could be generic service objects... Voted to close because I can only conjecture.

Comment: @Quaternion: These objects are services related to the (logged in) user.  When the user logs in I want to load these objects to show them to him. Then the user can edit them (change services state, for example). Some of this services have attached events (ex: when state changes does something).
I'd prefer not to load the services (with all the information they have) and attach the necessary events on every page load.
What do you mean by "generic service objects"?

Comment: @DaveNewton: That's precisely my question. Where else can I keep it? :)

Comment: @Nahoot You'll be taking up identical system resources regardless of where you keep it. I still don't understand the problem. Only *you* can decide if rebuilding the object graph is "too expensive" vs. the cost of keeping it in memory. We don't know enough to provide advice with any meaning.

Comment: The only thing you need in the session, is some object which uniquely identifies the user. Using a set of service methods which somehow can determine what user is logged in (one way would be to pass the user object as a parameter), you can get what you need per request. You need to weigh this against "in-memory, per-user" which as Dave mentioned by definition _is_ the session. The former would be the _where else_ you are looking for, if that happens to be tractable is another matter.

Comment: I don't want to rebuild the objects on every request. That's clear. So the problem is, where to keep them. To me, from a conceptual point of view, the session should be only for some how small objects (ex: user id, user name, etc..) so that I can identify the user and fetch the objects from wherever they might be. My problem with keeping large and complex objects in session is purely "psychological". I was expecting some other place would exist to keep this type of things. I seems there isn't so session it is.

Comment: Although, recently (today :) ), I've heard of infinispan which is an in memory database. I still have to read a bit more about it but this might be a solution.